# Fetching A Specific Field In Access From One To Another Table

Tags: ms-access

I need help; I have created a table that stores the premium based on the following criteria:

```
Table_Policy_Premium
1. Category: A
2. Min Age: 0
3. Max Age: 20
4. Premium: USD1000
```

The same category may have other ranges of age, min 21 max 64, and premium in the next field.

I have another table namely `employee_data,` where there is a premium field; I want that to be updated from a TPP table based on the following criteria against each employee.

If `Table_Policy_Premium` - `Category` Matches with `Category` in `employee_data`, and If the age in `employee_data` is between 0-20, update the premium field in `Employee_Table` from `Table_Policy_Premium` with the appropriate premium.

Comment: OK.  Have you tried anything?  And when/how is this update supposed to take place?  What event will trigger it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create public function in module that you will call in query (or on form), that will return premium value for given category and age.

```
Public Function getPremium(strCat As String, intAge as Integer) As Double

    'variables
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim rstQuery As dao.Recordset
    Dim dbs As dao.Database

    'set database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    'prepare query
    strQuery = "SELECT Premium " & _
                "FROM Table_Policy_Premium " & _
                "WHERE Category = '" & strCat & "' AND " & _
                "[Min Age] <= " & intAge & " AND " & _
                "[Max Age] >= " & intAge & ";"


    'open recordset
    Set rstQuery = dbs.OpenRecordset(strQuery)

    'check if there is a record
    If rstQuery.EOF Then

        'no record - set premium to 0
        getPremium = 0
    Else

        'record found
        getPremium = rstQuery!Premium
    End If

    Set rstQuery = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing

End Function
```

Simply call function by inserting this as field in query: getPremium([category],[age])